# Dynamically deserializing to a property in RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am playing with the Harvest API and I'm trying to automatically map the entities as easy as possible, unfortunately when I do a request like `GET /projects` it generates a result like so:

```
[{
    project: {
        name: "Test"
    }
},
{
    project: {
        name: "Test 2"
}]
```

In RestSharp, I can't directly do this:

```
client.Execute<List<Project>>(request)
```

Because it is going to look for a property called `Project`. So I have to make another class that has that property, and call it like this:

```
client.Execute<List<ProjectContainer>>(request)
```

I don't want to make a 'container' class for every entity, so I thought I found a clever solution to make one class I can use on all:

```
public class ListContainer<T> where T : IHarvestEntity
{
    public T Item { get; set; }
}
```

But, of course, the deserializer has no idea it needs to map the entity name (or "Project") to the property `Item`. In the restsharp documentation I found that I could use `[DeserializeAs(Name = "CustomProperty")]` to tell the deserializer which field to map to this property. However, attributes do only allow constants, which means I can't do:

```
[DeserializeAs(Name = typeof(T).FullName)]
public T Item { get; set; }
```

Does anyone know a clever solution to this? So i don't have to create 10 different container classes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest you use the XPath equivalent for Json. With Json.NET you can [parse](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonObject.htm) the string and create a dynamic object.

With [SelectToken](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm) you can query values, or using [Linq](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenWithLinq.htm).

The code looks something like this (I did not test it):

```
// execute the request
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content; // raw content as string

JObject o = JObject.Parse(content);

IList<string> projectNames = o.SelectToken("project").Select(s => (string)s.name).ToList();
```

You can code the paths or configure the paths anyway you like.

--- Edit ---

Here's an example that I tested, converting the json string to a list of projects.

```
var projects = JArray.Parse(response.Content).Select(r => new Project(r["project"]["name"].Value<string>())).ToList();
```

Comment: Dynamic object is probably the answer to the question, but a lot of developers would caution you to just implement the XYZModel classes and use those; you get all the benefits and guarantees of your compiler and don't risk (the same class of) run-time exceptions.

Comment: Democratically I think I should give you the bounty, but I feel like that the answer from Mikko answers the question more correctly for my situation. Because in your example, I lose the automatic mapping to the entity which is the whole idea behind this. Am I wrong about this?

Comment: Mapping to an object is possible, using the project object from the answer of Mikko:  var project = new Project(o.SelectToken("project").SelectToken("name").Value)

Comment: @ap I've just had a service vendor change their api wildly and now I have to rewrite a bunch of contracts. I'm using dynamic to extract only the fields I need into a single flat class rather than nested mess of contracts that may change at any moment. Either method will fail at runtime if the contract changes. With dynamic you may own less code.

Answer (score 5):

To keep it really simple, you can use `List<dynamic>` and access the property/properties by name with a one-liner.

```
var names = client.Execute<List<dynamic>>(request).Data.Select(
              item => item["project"]["name"]).ToList(); // list of names
```

---

If this is not sufficient, then you could improvise your own mapper and extract a collection of e.g. `Project` instances:

```
var projects = client.Execute<List<dynamic>>(request).Data.Select(
                 item => Map<Project>(item)).ToList(); // list of Project instances
```

where `Map` method could be something like

```
public T Map<T>(dynamic item) where T : class
{
    // inline for clarity
    var mappings = new Dictionary<Type,Func<dynamic,object>>
        {
            { typeof(Project), map => new Project(map["project"]["name"]) }
        };

    return (T)mappings[typeof(T)].Invoke(item);
}
```

given `Project` is defined as

```
public class Project
{
    public Project(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```